# CX_Freeze: Python.exe not responding

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am trying to convert my text editor into an exe to sell it, but Windows says that python.exe is not responding when I try to convert it in cmd.

My file name is arshi.py.

Below is my setup.py:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

exe = Executable(
        script = "arshi.py",
        icon = "icon.PNG",
        targetName = "Arshi.exe",
        base = base
        )

setup(
    name = "Arshi Editor",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "A lightweight text editor for Python",
    author = "Henry Zhu",
    options = {'build_exe': {"packages": ["pygments"]}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

Comment: What if you make `arshi.py` do nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cx_freeze doesn't accept **.png** files, but rather only **.ico** files. Converting the **.png** file to an **.ico** file worked beautifully for me.